# unsolved error exception in laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, frameworks

I am currently following laravel tutorial in youtube, and now I am stuck in this error

can you guys help me solve this problem ? thanks in advance :)

> ErrorException in UrlGenerator.php line 296: Route [profile.index] not
>   defined. (View:
>   C:\Users\user\Desktop\belajarlaravel\resources\views\templates\partials\navigation.blade.php)
>   (View:
>   C:\Users\user\Desktop\belajarlaravel\resources\views\templates\partials\navigation.blade.php)
>   (View:
>   C:\Users\user\Desktop\belajarlaravel\resources\views\templates\partials\navigation.blade.php)

this is my route :

```
<?php


Route::get('/',[
  'uses'=>'\Chatty\Http\Controllers\HomeController@index',
  'as'=>'home',
]
);

Route::get('/signup',[
  'uses'=>'\Chatty\Http\Controllers\AuthController@getSignup',
  'as'=>'auth.signup',
  'middleware'=>['guest'],
]
);

Route::post('/signup',[
  'uses'=>'\Chatty\Http\Controllers\AuthController@postSignup',
  'as'=>'auth.postSignup',
  'middleware'=>['guest'],
]
);

Route::get('/signin',[
  'uses'=>'\Chatty\Http\Controllers\AuthController@getSignin',
  'as'=>'auth.signin',
  'middleware'=>['guest'],
]
);

Route::post('/signin',[
  'uses'=>'\Chatty\Http\Controllers\AuthController@postSignin',
  'as'=>'auth.postSignin',
  'middleware'=>['guest'],
]
);

Route::get('/signout',[
  'uses'=>'\Chatty\Http\Controllers\AuthController@getSignout',
  'as'=>'auth.signout',
]
);

Route::get('/search',[
  'uses'=>'\Chatty\Http\Controllers\SearchController@getResults',
  'as'=>'search.results',
]
);

Route::get('/user/{username}',[
  'uses'=>'\Chatty\Http\Controllers\ProfileController@getProfile',
  'as'=>'profile.index',
]
);


Route::get('/profile/edit',[
  'uses'=>'\Chatty\Http\Controllers\ProfileController@getEdit',
  'as'=>'profile.edit',
  'middleware'=>['auth'],
]
);

Route::get('/user/{username}',[
  'uses'=>'\Chatty\Http\Controllers\ProfileController@postEdits',
  'middleware'=>['auth'],
]
);
```

and this is the **navigation.blade**

```
 @endif
 <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
     @if(Auth::check())
         <li><a href="{{route('profile.index', [
             'username' => Auth::user()->username
         ]) }}">{{Auth::user()->getNameorUsername()}}</a></li>
         <li><a href="{{route('profile.edit')}}">Update profile</a></li>
         <li><a href="{{route('auth.signout')}}">Sign out</a></li>
     @else
         <li><a href="{{route('auth.signup')}}">Sign up</a></li>
         <li><a href="{{route('auth.signin')}}">Sign in</a></li>
     @endif
 </ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

You've got 2 duplicate routes, by nature, the last one overrides all the previous,

```
Route::get('/user/{username}',[
  'uses'=>'\Chatty\Http\Controllers\ProfileController@getProfile',
  'as'=>'profile.index',
]
);

...
// this one is the last
Route::get('/user/{username}',[
  'uses'=>'\Chatty\Http\Controllers\ProfileController@postEdits',
  'middleware'=>['auth'],
]
```

Each route should be unique, absolutely unique.

Comment: aah, I see, so routes cannot be duplicated, even they have different name/as, thanks @pete :)